# Why np.mean applied to a pandas string column does not yield an error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How does the logic of calculating a mean on a string column work (the result is `246.8`)? Is there any specific use case for it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = np.array(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"])
pd.DataFrame(s).mean()

Out[1]: 
0    246.8
dtype: float64
```

Just to be clear, I am aware that to calculate the mean of numbers, I should do something along these lines.

```
pd.DataFrame(s.astype(int)).mean()

Out[2]: 
0    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that the strings are getting concatenated (which is the addition of strings), forming the string `"01234"`, which gets cast into the number `1234`, then, `1234 / 5 = 246.8`. This will only happen if the strings are numerical, i.e. they represent numbers in a string format, try adding a non-numerical string (e.g. `"x"` or `"hello"`) to the list and you will see that it will not work.